# How to make alertDialog not lose focus until dismiss() is called

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My `alertDialog closes` when I minimize my app. I don't want it to until `alertBuilder.dismiss()` is called. Also my `alertBuilder` depends on some user inputs so its not possible to open it again on activity resume. So how not to lose focus of it?

EDIT: My alertBuilder has some links in it and when user presses on one of the links,it is redirected to another app and then the alertBuilder closes.I want this not to happen.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can setCancelable(false) on your alert dialog.

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Your Title")
            .setMessage("Your Message")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",null)//optional
            .show();
```

This way alert dialog does not close on **activity minimize** or **back press**.

Clicking positive or negative button finally dismisses alert dialog so these buttons might be provisions to dismiss the alert dialog.

You can supply **null** as onClickListener parameter, if don't want to execute any code on button click. This also dismisses alert dialog.

Comment: Noo man! That wasn't my question. Even if you put setCancellable(false) in there but it still closes when you open any other app from any item click in the alertDialog. I want it not to close at that time.